# What is the latest ruby way to create an event handler for listening to a serial port?

Tags: ruby, events, rubygems, serial-port, eventmachine

I'm using [serialport](http://rubygems.org/gems/serialport) gem to read incoming data. The [ruby-serialport gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-serialport) is too old. An event handling gem for serial port usage is [em-serialport](http://rubygems.org/gems/em-serialport), but it's obsolete. I guess a good way would be to use [serialport](http://rubygems.org/gems/serialport) together with [eventmachine](http://rubygems.org/gems/eventmachine). But the code snippet "[EM over a Serial Port](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/wiki/Code-Snippets#em-over-a-serial-port)" does not work (no Streamobject class; Reactor class of [io-reactor](http://rubygems.org/gems/io-reactor) gem is from 2008 (obsolete?)).

So what is the latest or best way to handle serial input via events?

Comment: Define "too old" and "does not work". You can probably jump into the gem definition and tweak it, and it's possible that all you need to do is bump version numbers of dependencies.

Comment: "Too old" means the gem (ruby-serialport here) has not been updated since 2009. In contrast 'serialport' is much more popular and was last updated in 2012. The explanation for "does not work" is indicated within the brackets. I asked this to be on the safe side to not forge the wheel again if a good way already exist.

Comment: Hmm. Check out "artoo.io", they may have something to put you on the right track.